# URL No Longer Exists when i publish the site page

Tags: site.com

I have created a site page and after that i have published it. I received an email regarding the published of the site page. But when i clicked on the link i am getting error that URL No Longer Exists. This is the link to site : [enter link description here](https://partner360-developer-edition.na15.force.com/cmfocus/s)

do anybody have any idea why this issue is getting displayed.

Comment: this is not VF page, is site.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you are seeing the URL No Longer Exists error message because you haven't set the home page for your site.com site.

Thank you for posting the URL to your site. It makes it a lot easier to debug and see what is going on. This being a public .force.com domain means that it is either a Force.com Site or a Salesforce Community. The `/s/` string after your community prefix (`cmfocus`) means that you're using the Site.com portion of the community.

**To set the home page for your site.com site in a community:**

1. Go to the Community setup page (Setup -> Customize -> Communities -> Manage Communities)
2. Click the Site.com link under the custom pages header for the community you want to customize.
3. Create a site.com page to use as your home page.
4. Click Site Configuration on the left hand side of the Site.com studio.
5. Notice that the Home Page value is currently set to -Not Set-
6. Click the Edit button at the top of the page
7. Select your newly created page to use as the Home Page
8. Click Save
9. Publish your Site.com site (*Publish Changes...* button at the top of the page)

**Site Configuration Screenshot:**

[image: Site Configuration Screenshot]

Comment: that was awesome

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a Site.com page in Communities.  Are you trying to view the page unauthenticated?  If so, it is possible that your page is not available publicly.  See [setting custom authorization](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_auth_custom.htm&language=en_US).  You can set the page to be private by setting the folder it's in to Requires Authorization or by setting its own Requires Authorization.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Visualforce components in your site? If yes, this requires granting explicit permissions. Go to Setup -> Security Controls -> Session Setting -> 
Enable clickjack protection for non-setup customer Visualforce pages.

Enabling this option will cause this error. To correct the situation simply disable this option.

Comment: You cannot use Visualforce components in Site.com.

Comment: Has this changed lately? I clearly remember using VF components for a template page to pass attribute data to my home page.

Comment: No. Site.com has never supported Visualforce pages.  Force.com Sites does, though.